# Alternative note apps to marginnote in Windows environment

Tags: windows, note-taking, microsoft-onenote

I'm looking for a windows app to take notes and highlight texts in pdf and making outliners and mindmap efficiently. After some research, I found the closet app is marginnote, but there is only has iOS version for marginnote. Is there a similar app in Windows?

I know diigo is a choice, but it has to upload the pdf every time, which is a hassle to me.

Thanks for your help!

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a software called Docear. 
Docear is free, open source, available for Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X.
Docear, you can sort documents into categories; you can sort annotations (comments, bookmarks, and highlighted text from PDFs) into categories; you can sort annotations within PDFs; and you can view multiple annotations of multiple documents, in multiple categories.
http://www.docear.org