# Alternative note apps to Marginnote 3 in-windows environment,which can create flashcards on the fly

Tags: windows, pdf, ios, ubuntu

[A similar question was asked before](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/37562/alternative-note-apps-to-marginnote-in-windows-environment) , but decor does not have  cloze or image occlusion flashcard creation ability, on the fly.

In MarginNote 3, An user can crop out a section of document by selecting and apply image occlusion and export it as .apkg.

I believe this the best way to create IO cards quickly.

The closest software was an [anki add-on](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1781298089), but it's not as robust as margin note 3.

I also tried requesting margin note dev. to support windows OS,  they gave discount coupon to buy marginnote 3 for mac, without responding to the actual question, and subsequent contact attempts didn't help as, they didn't reply.

## Main Question

1. IS there is a way to run margin note 3 on windows/ubuntu without having to use an emulator.
2. Or if there an alternative app, which is as robust as margin note 3,

please let me know